# Text scrolls outside of the UITextView box boundary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView that has some text in it. The problem is that the text scrolls outside of the boundaries of the UITextView box. (The UITextView is uneditable.)

here's the code and what I have tried to resolve this issue:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

        textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    //  textBG.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        textBG.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
        textBG.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
        [textBG setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView*)textView
{

textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;    
 [textBG setClipsToBounds:YES];   
}

- (void) shouldChangeTextInRange:(UITextView*)textView {

    textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;    
    [textBG setClipsToBounds:YES];

}
```

thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `"text scrolls outside of the boundaries"`?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

write this in textView delegate methods like textViewDidBeginEditing

```
textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

in viewDidload

```
[textBG setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: same problem i faced before two days just i put  textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero; in shouldChangeTextInRange and textViewDidBeginEditing methods.its working fine in my case ..

Comment: then put [textBG setClipsToBounds:YES]; i think it will work fine

Comment: I tried your answer and it worked for the text out of boundary issue. But my view had a shadow, when I used `clipsToBounds = YES`, the shadow wouldn't show up. Any solution to keep the shadow? @Narayana

Comment: @Gon: Did you ever find a solution for it?

Comment: worked for me. textBG.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero in swift 4

Answer (score 2):

Try to change in XIB for your TextView like below:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just put this one line code to solve problem.

```
yourTextView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem, so I track down the source ... this is because of while adding shadow somehow you disturbed it's **masksToBounds** property. Therefore, while adding more text it got overflowed. Simple solution which I found is to write this simple line after adding shadow.

```
[self.myTextView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

usually should be in **viewDidLoad** method, but remember to write this line only **after** applying **shadow**.

Thanks for reading this.