# Text outside of UITextView boundaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, quartz-core

In my iOS app, I am trying to add shadows to a `UITextView` using QuartzCore, but I end up with text scrolling outside of the bounds of the `UITextView`:

[image]

I have tried to use the solutions at [Text scrolls outside of the UITextView box boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607907/text-scrolls-outside-of-the-uitextview-box-boundary), however none of the solutions worked. The first solution, `textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`, does absolutely nothing to the `UITextView` when I place it in the `viewDidLoad` method. The second solution gets rid of the shadow that I'm trying to add: `[textView setClipsToBounds:YES];`.

Here is the Quartz Core code I'm using to create the shadow:

```
textView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
textView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
textView.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug in iOS? If so, are there any workarounds or solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text scrolls outside of the UITextView box boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607907/text-scrolls-outside-of-the-uitextview-box-boundary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for get content size :

```
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.contentSize.width, textView.contentSize.height);
```